# what is wrong with my javascript constructors and related syntax

Tags: javascript

EDIT: Thank you to all who responded. I'm in the process of checking it with just console.log for the desired output, but at the moment I do know that it is not doing what I want with HTML. Anyone else know what could be wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT 2: The function "functions" when I define "television" directly within the console, but other than that, I can't figure out how to have television defined in the code. I took it out of the start(); function because I thought it might be out of scope. That didn't work either.

```
// Program Name: Television Store
// Television Store Website.

    /* Constructor Function: */
        function TelInput(ret, man, scr, conf, dis) {
        this.ret = parseInt(ret, 10);
        this.man = man;
        this.scr = parseInt(scr, 10);
        this.discount = this.ret * 0.9;
        this.dis = dis;
        this.conf = conf  
    };

var start = function(){    
/* Initial Variables */
var screen = prompt("Enter the screen size of TV in inches: ");
var manufacturer = prompt("Enter the manufacturer of TV: ");
var retail = prompt("Enter the retail value of TV: ");
var priceConf = confirm("Apply the 10% discount?");
var dispValues = confirm("Display Values when Finsihed?");

/* Display the Values */

console.log(television.ret);
console.log(television.man);
console.log(television.scr);
console.log(television.discount);

    if(television.conf){
        document.getElementById("l4").innerHtml = "Discounted Price:  " + television.dis;   
    }
};
console.log("Program Completed."); // Confirm Javascript functions.
start(); // Start function.
var television = new TelInput(retail, manufacturer, screen, priceConf, dispValues); // Create object
```

Comment: Not an answer, but noticed: it looks like you didn't set `this.dis` and `this.conf` in your  constructor. You need to either set these values to your object or make it `if (dis) { ...; if (conf) { ... } }`, without `this`.

Comment: You're missing the `new` keyword. `var television = new telInput(retail, manufacturer, screen, priceConf, dispValues);`. Also, constructors are usually capitalized by convention.

Comment: Oh yeah, I took that out to see if it run just as a normal function that way... Apparently that didn't help. Will "TelInput" not being capitalized effect its functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `telInput` is supposed to be constructor function:

- Call it with `new`: `var television = new telInput(retail, manufacturer, screen, priceConf, dispValues);`. Right now the properties `ret`, `man`, etc will be assigned to `window` and `television` will be `undefined`.
- Pascal-case constructor functions: `TelInput`. This is a very strong convention. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function).

A few other issues:

- You are not assigning `dis` and `conf` to any property: add `this.dis = dis; this.conf = conf`.
- `this.discount = ret * 0.9;` this should probably be `this.discount = this.ret * 0.9;` as `this.ret` contains the parsed value.

Comment: Thank you! I'll revise it and run it again. For the record I voted up, but I have < 15 rep apparently...